# How to add product category to page title as data attribute?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, category, category-products, category-attribute

I am brand new to Magento and am a Wordpress developer and am trying to get my bearings on something that seems like it should be simple to accomplish. I am trying to simply add a data-attribute to my product title on the product details page. I want to do this so I can add some logic in my JS based on it. The issue is despite the research I have done I cannot get it to work.

I have located the title.phtml file and tried adding in

```
data-category="<?php echo $block->getCurrentCategory->getId() ?>"
```

but when I reload the page it is just white.

What is the easiest way to go about this? In wordpress I can literally just do the_title() and it gets the title of the post. Is there something similar by chance?

Answer (score 0):

Product title (product name) in product detail page define in

> vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product</argument>
                <argument name="add_base_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="name"</argument>
            </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

i think the easiest way to go about this is create plugin.

> app/code/Company/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="training_catalog_product" type="Company\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Product"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Company/Module/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Product.php

```
class Product
{
    public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        $title = $subject->getAttributeText('other_name');
        return $title;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply but I think you may have misread. I am looking to get the product category and add it into the title.